# Can you declare an attribute private within an abstract class?

Tags: php, oop

Let's say you have an abstract class:

```
abstract class PersonAbstract
{
    private $name = "Stack Overflow";
}
```

Is it legal to declare an attribute as **private** within an abstract class? Or the fact that this class should be extended, the minimum visibility is **protected**?

Comment: I don't do PHP, but I think it could be legal and senseful as long as you have at least one method in PersonAbstract which use the variable.

Comment: Yes, it is legal. Although the class is `abstract`, the classes that derive from it may still call its `protected / public` methods, those methods *do* have access to the `private` variable.

Comment: @Anas you can declare private attribute but you cannot access it in extending class.

Comment: You can create private attribute in abstract class, but not functions. check: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php `the function implementation must be defined as either protected or public, but not private`

Comment: @Anas functions can be private too. You've taken a quote out of context - overriding `methods must be defined with the same (or a less restricted) visibility. For example, if the abstract method is defined as protected, the function implementation must be defined as either protected or public, but not private`. A private abstract function isn't possible though, which may be what you meant.

Comment: @stwalkerster yep, that's what I meant...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can have a private field within an abstract class. This field will only be accessible to functions within that abstract class though. Any classes which inherit from your abstract class will not be able to access the field.

You can declare both fields and functions as public, protected or private within an abstract class. If a field or function is public, it is accessible to anyone. If it is protected, it is accessible only to that class, and any classes which inherit from that class. If it is private, it is only accessible to that class.

Abstract functions must be implemented by an inheriting class, so it makes no sense (and probably won't work) to have a private abstract function.