# Trying to reuse code, but can't extend two classes, alternative?

Tags: php, extend

I know I cannot extend from two classes, but what is the alternative for my case?

I am using a base class, `parser`, that parser the page of my CMS. This class contains all the basic functions needed to filter the data retrieved from the database and rendering it into a HTML page.

All the other classes NEED the parser, because without it they don't work.

I have 2 modes:

1. Inside the CMS
2. Outside the CMS

**Inside CMS**

If inside the CMS, userdata and other additional data is loaded into the class.

**Outside CMS**

If outside the CMS, only the necessary data to render the page is loaded, this is the default way for displaying pages to people who visit the site.

---

**Modules**

A page can be used to display default data/elements, but it can also be used to display data from a module (e.g. a calender page).
If this is the case, additional data needs to be loaded into the parser object, and thus I have 4 different use cases:

1. parser mode
2. cmsParser mode (inside CMS)
3. moduleParser mode (parser with module data loaded)
4. cmsModuleParser mode (both)

I have the following [extremely simplified] classes:

```
class parser {
   protected $oDataSource1;
   protected $oDataSource2;
   protected $oDataSource3;

   //... 
   public function filterData() {
       //.. Search through the data sources and return filtered data
   }
}

class cmsParser extends parser {
   protected $sUser_name;
   protected $iUser_id;
   protected $sUserLanguage;

   ///.. some functions here that are called only within the CMS
}

class moduleParser extends parser {
    protected $mModuleData;
    //.. Do something with this moduleData;
}

class cmsModuleParser extends ?? {
    //... Get functions from the cmsParser + module functions
}
```

The only solution I can come up with is using a trait that the moduleParser and the cmsModuleParser both use? 
This is not optimal IMO, because I still have to add duplicate variables etc.

I don't want duplicate code, of course, so how do I solve this puzzle?

Comment: Any reason why the parser loads the data into itself and doesn't just return a data-object that can be used by other classes? That would allow you to just pass a parser-instance to any class that needs it, and let it parse as many things as that class needs parsed.

Comment: The main reason for using the parser class is to encapsulate the data and have a central point to get my data on later points in the parsing process. You can include PHP snippets in a page, and by keeping all the data in a parser class, I immediately know what I can or cannot use.

Comment: You can extend once class, but implement multiple class. Maybe you should try using interfaces.

Comment: That might be the only workable solution I guess

Comment: If you feel like that's the only solution then I will post it as an answer!!

Comment: I would split the parser data into a separate class. That will also solve your problem I think.

Comment: @AjitKumarSingh I am trying to use interfaces now, but there is one big issue: interface functions and variables can only be defined public... I rather not want to do that..

Comment: You can create private variables in abstract class. Here is the link for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28540620/can-you-declare-an-attribute-private-within-an-abstract-class

Comment: @Erik, The parser is made to retreive multiple data objects and output the data after filtering it on certain aspects. So if I use a different class to encapsulate the data, another layer is added to the system, which complicates the getting and setting of data

Comment: @AjitKumarSingh, this creates the same issue, I can only extend one abstract class.

Comment: @AjitKumarSingh http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php

Comment: @Abayob Well then, i have no other solution. Unless it was C++. With PHP you can extend one and implement Many. Only if the security for that piece of code is not a priority, I would suggest Interfaces.

Comment: Well, thank you all for your comments, I can work with this. I am going to create a module class that gets instanciated on construction and an interface to access the module object from outside the class. Thanks for the input all!!

Comment: I think you have your relationship between classes a bit wrong.  By inheriting from your parser you're implying that your subclasses are parsers too (is_a relationship).  But if you think about it, a CMS page is not a parser.  It might need a parser to provide it with a service (has_a relationship).  If you make the parser a stand-alone class and inject an instance of it into your CMS class then you will break the is_a relationship.

Comment: @GordonM, well it is definitely an extension of the parser, but I guess that my example is to basic to describe this to you. The CMS parser takes over some parser functions and adds validation and data to it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard the phrase **favor composition over inheritance**? Sometimes, Composition would pay more than Inheritance. In this case, the `cmsModuleParser extends cmsParser` and then injects the `moduleParser` via the constructor as a Dependency. However, you also have a `getter` and a `setter` for the `$moduleParser` Property. So if you don't need it to be injected via the Constructor, you may still remove it from the constructor and use the `setModuleParser()` Accessor Method instead. **Alternatively, you may also Program To Interface**. Below is a code that would illustrate both concepts:

**COMPOSITION**

```
    <?php
        class parser {
            protected $mData;

            //...
            public function filterData() {
                //.. filter the data here and return it
            }
        }

        class cmsParser extends parser {
            protected $sUser_name;
            protected $iUser_id;
            protected $sUserLanguage;

            ///.. some functions here that are called only within the CMS
        }

        class moduleParser extends parser {
            protected $mModuleData;
            //.. Do something with this moduleData;
        }

        // HERE YOU EXTEND THE cmsParser 
        // AND THEN USING DI, INCLUDE THE moduleParser
        class cmsModuleParser extends cmsParser {
            /**
             * @var ModuleParser
             */
            protected $moduleParser;
            //... Get functions from the cmsParser + module functions

            public function __construct(moduleParser $moduleParser) {
            }

            /**
             * @return moduleParser
             */
            public function getModuleParser() {
                return $this->moduleParser;
            }

            /**
             * @param moduleParser $moduleParser
             * @return cmsModuleParser
             */
            public function setModuleParser($moduleParser) {
                $this->moduleParser = $moduleParser;

                return $this;
            }

        }
```

**PROGRAMMING TO INTERFACE**

```
    <?php
        interface iParser{
            public function filterData();
            public function renderView();
            public function saveData();

        }

        class parser implements iParser{
            protected $mData;

            //...
            public function filterData() {
                //.. filter the data here and return it
            }

            public function renderView(){}
            public function saveData(){}
        }

        class cmsParser extends parser {
            protected $sUser_name;
            protected $iUser_id;
            protected $sUserLanguage;

            ///.. some functions here that are called only within the CMS
        }

        class moduleParser extends parser {
            protected $mModuleData;
            //.. Do something with this moduleData;
        }


        class cmsModuleParser implements iParser {
            //... Get functions from the cmsParser + module functions

            public function __construct() {
            }

            public function filterData(){}
            public function renderView(){}
            public function saveData(){}

        }
```

Comment: But the moduleParser and the cmsParser both are extensions of the parser class. Doesn't this load in duplicate code into the memory?

Comment: @Abayob      In that case, you may simply remove the constructor-based injection and then manually call `setModuleParser` only when it is necessary. Here is a typical proof of the phrase: *favor composition over inheritance*.... Alternatively, you may decide not to extend no class but then use composition for the `moduleParser` and `cmsParser`. That way your `cmsModuleParser` class is **composed** of both classes yet inheriting from neither. Another way is to `Program to Interfaces`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to Know the fact that all classes extends a single class considered as a bad design and indicated that you have bad understanding about OO concepts.

Inheritence is somethig like `A is a B`. That is, all your classes IS A cmsParser. This of course is wrong and will cause problems like these you are reffering to. There are many examples where inheritence is usefull like

- Woman is a human
- Toyota is a Car
- PageController is a Controller (more common scenario at MVC
  applications)

But inheritance like

- Car is an Engine
- Womans is a Leg
- cmsModuleParser is Parser

is not a good design and the issue is obvious.

**So how you adress your problem?**
 Lets stick to `Car` case. First define the Car class

```
class Car extends Engine{

    public function reverse(){
    $this->startEngine();//Parent's method.
    .....
    }
```

instead of the above you can do something like this

```
class Car{
protected $Engine;
protected $Driver;

public function __construct($Engine, $Driver){
$this->Engine = $Engine;
$this->Driver = $Driver;
}

public function reverse(){
$this->Engine->start();
$this->Driver->LookBehindYou();
...
}

}
```

With that way using contstructor injection you have loose coupling between your depedencies and you have a better design.

Search at google about *Depedency Injection* and *Composition over inheritance* consepts.